# Is it possible to build a metro interface app with Vb.net in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-metro

we've been asked to change a webapp we're making to metro interface, the thing is, we have only Visual Studio 2005, what should we do to be able to change our app to Metro?

Answer (score 3):

You will need Visual Studio 2012 as far as I am aware. You can use the free [Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-8#product-express-windows) of Visual Studio 2012 for building Windows 8 Apps. You will also need to be running Windows 8. You cannot develop Windows 8 Apps on Windows 7, Vista, or any other OS version less than 8.

You can install the Express Edition of 2012 along side Visual Studio 2005 and have them run side-by-side, it doesn't replace 2005, so you can keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as doing it within visual studio 2005 I don't think it's possible. But what you would need is the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx).

You may be able to get by with the open source IDE [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). I haven't used it in a long time so I'm not sure how far you'll get with it.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements for Developing windows 8 Application :-

1 -> Visual Studio 2012
2 -> Windows 8 Latest Version 
3 -> Developer License.

[Windows Store App Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx)

Once you are done with this remeber you need to meet certain criteria listed below

[App certification and requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx)

Now answer to your original question

> with visual studio 2005 you wont be able to build the app as 1,2 are the basic requirements, hence forth once you start you can go through the links below to make ur app perfet for the windows store

Note : one bad news . Ull have to code entire thing again as metro is a subset of the win32 api's and it will not even recognize some of them .